# Size of icon image for UIActivity in ios?

Tags: ios, uiactivitytypeairdrop

I am creating a custom `UIActivity.Image`. What size should return by function `activityImage`?

Currently I have implemented it like this.

```
override func activityImage()-> UIImage {
   return UIImage(named: "Icon-Small@3x.png")!
}
```

Comment: From https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiactivity/1620658-activityimage : "For iPhone and iPod touch, images on iOS 7 should be 60 by 60 points; on earlier versions of iOS, you should use images no larger than 43 by 43 points. For iPad, images on iOS 7 should be 76 by 76 points; on earlier versions of iOS you should use images no larger than 60 by 60 points. On a device with Retina display, the number of pixels is doubled in each direction."

Comment: minimum supported version is iOS 8. should I give image of 60 by 60 ?

Comment: Apparently, 60*60 for non-retina, 120*120 for retina, and 180*180 for High Retina

Answer (score 1):

In case you use a SF Symbol image, you must use a `.large` scale format in order to get an image with the same size as system `UIActivity` items:

```
override var activityImage: UIImage? {
    return UIImage(systemName: "safari", withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .large))
}
```